# Hidding Navbar with React Router V4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a simple frontend application, and I'm using React Router V4, I'm trying to hide the navbar on the `Login` and `Register` screens.

Here is my `App.js` code

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isNavbarHidden: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const currentRoutes = this.props.location;
    if (currentRoutes === "/") {
      this.setState({ isNavbarHidden: true });
    }
  } // end of componentDidMount
  render() {
    const { isNavbarHidden } = this.state;
    console.log(isNavbarHidden);
    return (
      <div>
        {!isNavbarHidden && <Navigation />}
        <div className="sans-serif">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/Register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/Home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and I have this in `index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I thought when I did the if statement in `componentDidMount` that would have fixed the issue, however on route `'/'` the navbar is still shown

[NavBar shown above login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neimF.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of `const currentRoutes = this.props.location;` you want something like `const currentRoute = this.props.location.pathname`.

`this.props.location` is an Object, so your condition will never be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` will only be called once when your `App` component is mounted.

You could listen to changes in the `history` in `componentDidMount` instead, and change `isNavbarHidden` if the `pathname` is `/` or `/Register`.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { pathname } = this.props.location;
    this.state = {
      isNavbarHidden: pathname === "/" || pathname === "/Register"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen(location => {
      const { pathname } = location;
      const isNavbarHidden = pathname === "/" || pathname === "/Register";

      this.setState({ isNavbarHidden });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();
  }

  render() {
    const { isNavbarHidden } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {!isNavbarHidden && <Navigation />}
        <Link to="/">Login</Link>
        <Link to="/Register">Register</Link>
        <Link to="/Home">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/Dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
        <div className="sans-serif">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/Register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/Home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```